# Java overloading a method with two parameters

Tags: java, overloading

This problem is about overloading methods and I think I understand the basic idea but I get some weird error "Overloading.java:14".
Like my problem is that I don't know how to return two parameters of my method. So I thought maybe convert the method with the two int parameters with toString(), then return it. Something gone miserably wrong.
The output have to be following:

a 10

a and b 10, 20

char a

result 97

My problem as it is, is with the "a and b 10, 20", and have not done the "char a" just to make you guys aware. This is **not** homework.
Here is my code so far contains a main class and a helper class:

**OverMain Class :**

```
class OverMain {   
     public static void main(String args[]) {   
        Overload overload = new Overload();   
        int result;   
        System.out.println("a " + overload.test(10));  //prints a 10
            System.out.println("a and b " + overload.test(10, 20));  //the method I have trouble with
        result = overload.test('a'); //prints Result 97
        System.out.println("Result " + result);   
     }   
}
```

**Overload Class:**

```
//The class which is suppose to overload test methods
class Overload {

  public int test(int a) {
    return a;
  }

  public String test(int a, int b) {
    String string = "";
       string = test(a, b).toString();
       return string;
  }

}
```

Comment: Jon Skeet for  rescue.

Comment: You have an unbounded recursive loop in your `test(int a, int b)` method: it's calling itself until the stack overflows.

Comment: why you are calling `test(a, b)` from `test(int a, int b)`
that's endless recursion

Comment: So you got a StackOverflow, and then googled for "StackOverflow", and came to this website? :-) StackOverflow means you have an infinite recursion.

Comment: Note that you can't overload on return type, not in Java at least.

Comment: @Ingo actually you can, by making it more specific (for example return String in a subclass, instead of Object as in the base class)

Comment: @Ingo Oh that's helpful I did not know that. I made it work, appreciate your help.

Comment: @ThomasMueller I would call this subtyping, not overloading.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Lol I did not know at first sight it was a overflow :). But it makes sense, the recursion never ends as mention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but you don't *return* parameters, and I don't think overloading is really the problem here. To take overloading out of the situation, you can always change the methods to have different names - get it working that way, and then you can always change the names back later and work out any conflicts.

In your case I think you just need:

```
public String test(int a, int b) {
    return a + ", " + b;
}
```

In other words, just use string concatenation and the automatic `int` to `String` conversion that the compiler will apply in order to use string concatenation.

Note that if your code actually compiled, you'd get a stack overflow because you're calling `test(a, b)` from `test(int a, int b)` - it would just call itself forever, until you ran out of stack space.

Comment: I actually tried that but forget to change the line "public String.." from "public int...". Thx!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your method `test(int, int)`

```
public String test(int a, int b) {

  String string = "";
  string = test(a, b).toString(); // Danger
  return string;
}
```

- You have a never ending recurrence relation
- **Solution:** `return a + ", " + b`